# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'todo\views\DataBase' not found

Tags: php, oop, composer-php, autoload

I am using `composer` to `autoload` my classes.

My Folder structure:

```
mytodo
     - src
        -app
            IDb.php
        -views
            db.php
            todos.php
     - web
         index.php
     -composer.json
```

Trying to inherit `Database` class from `todos.php` `__constructor()`. But giving this error!!!

todos.php

```
<?php
namespace todo\views;
use todo\app\IDb;

class Todo extends DataBase implements IDb{

    public function __construct() 
    {
         $newdb = new DataBase();
         $connection = $newdb->connect();
    }
}
```

composer.json

```
{
    "name": "todo/website",
    "description": "This is a TODO App",
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "todo\\": "src/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.2.0"
    }
}
```

db.php

```
<?php
namespace todo\views;
use todo\app\IDb;

abstract class DataBase implements IDb{

    private $user;
    private $host;
    private $pass;
    private $db;
    protected $connection;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = "root";
        $this->host = "localhost";
        $this->pass = "";
        $this->db = "db_todos";
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $connection = mysqli_connect($this->host, $this->user, $this->pass, $this->db);
        return $connection;
    }
}
?>
```

DB Interface:

```
<?php
namespace todo\app;

interface IDb {
    public function connect() : string;
}
```

Can't figure out the problem. Please help me in advance.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? I see multiple problems in your code: `new DataBase`  will throw an error if you don't have any non-abstract class called `DataBase` to be instantiated

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the faulty naming. PSR-4 autoloading implies that the filename matches the class name.

Solution: rename files according to class names: `todos.php` becomes `ToDo.php`, `db.php` becomes `DataBase.php`.

Comment: You can do it the other way around and rename classes instead, but it is not recommended, as class names usually start with uppercase letters by convention.